# How to Apply GaussianBlur filter on a CATextLayer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class FirstView: UIView {

    var copyright = CATextLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        ...

        if let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur",
                                     withInputParameters[kCIInputRadiusKey:20]
        {
            copyright.filters = [blurFilter]
        }
        layer.insertSublayer(copyright, at: 0)
    }

}
```

I could not find other ways. I want to be able to GaussianBlur any layer like a CAGradientLayer or CAShapeLayer

Comment: `CALayer` (and it's subclasses) are a basic component of a `UIView`. `CIFilter`, part of CoreImage, will *require* an input of a `CIImage`. There are ways to take a `UIView` (or say a `UIImage` or `CGImage`) and get a `CIImage` - but since you are talking about a `CALayer` subclass I'd look into converting a `UIView` into a `CIImage` and back. (Or yes, looking at something like GPUImage, which may require just about the same thing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filters` property isn’t available in iOS

> Special Considerations This property is not supported on layers in iOS.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410901-filters

Possibly you can use a third party blurring library. [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2) is popular and robust.